# Ошибка "Предполагается наличие ';'True"

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, yandex-maps-api

Хочу запустить некую проверку через js в консольном приложении .NET. Для этого написал след метод:

```
public static string Run(string script, string functionName, object[] parms)
    {
        MSScriptControl.ScriptControl scriptControl = new MSScriptControl.ScriptControl();
        scriptControl.AllowUI = false;
        scriptControl.Language = "JScript";
        scriptControl.Reset();
        scriptControl.AddCode(script);
        return scriptControl.Run(functionName, ref parms);
    }
```

В качестве script я подгружаю содержимое файла со скриптом

```
function Check(coords, address){return 'test';}
```

И если вызываю свой метод, то все работает

```
var run_result = JavaScriptRunner.Run(script, "Check", new object[] { coords, address });
```

Но мне нужно сделать проверку используя yandex api

```
https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?apikey=ваш API-ключ&lang=ru_RU
```

Я его тоже подгружаю и пытаюсь содержимое АПИ подключить след образом

```
var run_result = JavaScriptRunner.Run(api+script, "Check", new object[] { coords, address });
```

И меня ругает `scriptControl.AddCode(script);` с ошибкой `Предполагается наличие ';'True`
Есть кто пробовал делать что-то подобное, на что ругается, как обойти или api только через браузер откроется?

Comment: Последняя версия JScript вышла 11 лет назад, он даже древний ES5 не поддерживает, не говоря уже о более современных версиях JavaScript. Найдите какой-нибудь более современный js-движок

Comment: Также учтите, что тот скрипт по ссылке - лишь загрузчик, который для загрузки создаёт ещё несколько скриптов. Такая схема может работать только в браузере, поэтому вам нужен не просто движок js, а браузер в headless режиме.

Comment: Кстати, браузер в headless режиме нарушает правила использования API Яндекс карт.

Comment: Если ищете не браузерный JS, посовременнее, посмотрите в сторону библиотеки AngleSharp с плагином AngleSharp.JS